# Meaning of the arguments outside the operation? $(\nabla u \cdot \boldsymbol{n})(\boldsymbol{x},t)=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

What does it mean to write the arguments outside the functions, e.g. $(\nabla u \cdot \boldsymbol{n})(\boldsymbol{x},t)=0$?
$\boldsymbol{n}$ is the unit outward normal vector to a surface.

Does it mean $\nabla u(\boldsymbol{x},t) \cdot \boldsymbol{n}=0$ or $\nabla u(\boldsymbol{x},t) \cdot \boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x},t)=0$ or maybe something else?

Comment: What would mean $\nabla u(\boldsymbol{x},t) \cdot \boldsymbol{n}=0$? That $\boldsymbol{n}$ is constant?

Comment: It's the latter.

Comment: Yes, this notation means that scalar field $u$ is a function of position vector $\mathbf{x}$ and independent variable $t$, say a time variable. It can also be written as $(\mathbf{n}\cdot\nabla) u(\mathbf{x},t)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It's like $(fg) (x)$, which means $f(x) g(x)$. In your case it means

$$\big( (\nabla u) (x,t) \big) \cdot \big(\boldsymbol n(x,t) \big)$$

(with more paranthese added for more clarity).

Comment: Thanks! Are there any benefits with this notation? I have also seen the same notation for convolution, $(f \ast g)(t)$ instead of $f(t) \ast g(t)$.

Comment: @JDoeDoe: The notation for convolution is a vastly different thing, totally unrelated to the one discussed here. If you don't see the difference between them, you should reread your lecture notes.